# Ionic 2 Lifecycle-based Animations

Tags: animation, ionic-framework, ionic2

I created a tab-based Ionic 2 project and I'm using the following lifecycle hooks to define a trigger property for animations to occur when a given page loads:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.state = 'active';
  console.log(this.state);
}
ionViewWillLeave() {
  this.state = 'inactive';
  console.log(this.state);
}
```

This is what the animations looks like in the component decorator:

```
animations: [
    trigger('focusPanel', [
        state('inactive', style({
            opacity: '0'
        })),
        state('active', style({
            transform: 'translateY(-80px)',
            opacity: '1'
        })),
        transition('* <=> active', animate('.5s ease-out'))
    ]),
]
```

This works when the app loads.  I can click on a different tab and go back, and the animation works as expected.

However, if I go back a third time, while the console.log is accurate and consistent, the animations no longer play. It doesn't fade from 0 opacity, and it does not animate up based on translateY.

Any idea of what's going on? I've tried different lifecycle hooks, as well as different transition() properties in the animations above.

Comment: I am also facing some issue . Animation is loading with the page load which is creating issue